# How to use mechanize in pypy?

Tags: python, pypy

I used mechanize in Python, but peppy said

```
$ pypy
Python 2.7.9 (9c4588d731b7fe0b08669bd732c2b676cb0a8233, Mar 31 2015, 07:55:22)
[PyPy 2.5.1 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import mechanize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mechanize
>>>> import sys
>>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/site-packages/setuptools-14.3.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/lib_pypy/__extensions__', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/lib_pypy', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/lib-python/2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/lib-python/2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/lib-python/2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/lib-python/2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/lib-python/2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/pypy/2.5.1/libexec/site-packages']
```

Please tell me how to use mechanize in pypy.
I think I haven't create path but I don't know way.

Answer (score 0):

PyPy does not automatically pick CPython paths. You either need to install mechanize separately (I suggest virtualenv) or you need to put path to it into sys.path or PYTHONPATH environment variable.